# Gradient (nabla) of vector/array in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, vector, gradient

I am to implement the following formula in Delphi:

[image]

**Understanding the formula:**

Y_k is a floating point number which we'll call just Y.

w[i][j] is an array containing floating point numbers as well (1<=i<=43 and 1<=j<=30).

According to [my source paper](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Publications/Papers/2000100.pdf) (p. 12) **nabla(w)*Y_k** is the **partial derivative** of (column) vector w with respect to the value Y". Is this correct?

**Coding in Delphi (implementation):**

So how do I implement this in Delphi?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I am afraid that I havn't got time to read the article (not even the beginning thereof). You should first make sure that *you* understand what function you want to implement (otherwise, it is hard to implement it). Secondly, you need to design a data type that can hold the quantities used as input and output of this function, that is, the *interface*, or *signature*, of the function. (This might be a simple `array of real`.) Then, and not before that point, you can contemplate about how to implement the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I will assume that the problem is: "How can I compute a gradient of a scalar function in Delphi?"* [I still think that the symbol given above looks more like a connection/covariant derivative as known from differential geometry/tensor calculus!]

You need to specify the input you got. The simplest case is when you got the function *f* whose gradient you wish to compute. Per definition, if *f* is a function of the *k* variables *x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *x*<sub>*k*</sub>, that is, if you'd write

*f*(*x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *x*<sub>*k*</sub>)

which is a scalar field in ℝ<sup>*k*</sup> then the gradient is

∇*f* = (∂*f*/∂*x*<sub>1</sub>, ∂*f*/∂*x*<sub>2</sub>, ..., ∂*f*/∂*x*<sub>*k*</sub>)

that is, a vector field in ℝ<sup>*k*</sup> (at each point in ℝ<sup>*k*</sup> you get a *k*-dimensional vector).

This is rather easily implemented in Delphi. The following is an example for the case where *k* = 3.

```
type
  TVector = record
    x, y, z: real;
    constructor Create(ax, ay, az: real);
  end;
  TRealValuedFunction = function(v: TVector): real;

function gradient(f: TRealValuedFunction; v: TVector): TVector;
const
  h = 0.001;
begin
  result.x := (f(TVector.Create(v.x + h, v.y, v.z)) - f(TVector.Create(v.x - h, v.y, v.z))) / (2*h);
  result.y := (f(TVector.Create(v.x, v.y + h, v.z)) - f(TVector.Create(v.x, v.y - h, v.z))) / (2*h);
  result.z := (f(TVector.Create(v.x, v.y, v.z + h)) - f(TVector.Create(v.x, v.y, v.z - h))) / (2*h);
end;
```

where, of course,

```
constructor TVector.Create(ax, ay, az: real);
begin
  x := ax;
  y := ay;
  z := az;
end;
```

Sample usage:

```
function SampleFunction(v: TVector): real;
begin
  result := 5*v.x + 7*v.y;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with gradient(SampleFunction, TVector.Create(2, 6, 3)) do
    ShowMessage(FloatToStr(x) + ', ' + FloatToStr(y) + ', ' + FloatToStr(z))
end;
```

The result is `5.00000000000256, 7.000000000005, 0` which is a very good approximation to the gradient of `SampleFunction` at `v` (in this case the gradient is constant in space, that is, it doesn't depend on which point `v` in space you select).

Of course, if you are writing anything serious, you will probably use your own vector algebra library.

Also, `h = 0.001` might not be a great value in your case.